# How to learn SQLite Databsae in iphone?

Tags: sqlite, ios4

I am new in iPhone Developer so I want learn SQLite Database from begin to end so please send me any link or tutorials as soon as possible...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just googled it and found alot of tutorials, you can do the same.

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=21&gs_id=58&xhr=t&q=sqlite+iphone+tutorial&qe=c3FsaXRlIGlwaG9uZSB0dXRvcmlh&qesig=Dcyg8tTe9KFL_O0Vg2BS8g&pkc=AFgZ2tlQMpmwWA0F9wFG4yjq73f9sgv_HDMKi6K7YdUA1mzfYyLA9vcM0Su1JtgKX49HQ2ejjF2gmh4ZMfKlNLvZsc-NIkHJEw&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=sqlite+iphone+tutoria&aq=0&aqi=g2g-j2g-b1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=cd161f1f675bc69c&biw=1920&bih=876